# GKScores are stored until next connection?

Tags: ios, gamekit, leaderboard

In Apple's [GKLeaderboards](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GKLeaderboards/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code they show how to store GKScore objects for later submission when they fail to send. However, the documentation for [Reporting Scores To Game Center](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH6-SW14) says "If for some reason the score could not be reported because of a network error, Game Kit automatically resends the data when the network becomes available."

Does this mean that the resend infrastructure in GKLeaderboards is no longer necessary? In which version did GameKit start saving and resending scores to the leader board?

I haven't used GameKit until just recently, so I'm hoping someone has been using it for a while and can confirm it to save me some testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience I've never had to implement coeds to resend scores that were not able to be sent when a connection was down!

All data shows that with the automated resending, you and I no longer have to resend the data manually! :)

That's a relief.

Comment: I'm gonna take this as correct, since you have an app in the store and I don't -- yet! Thanks.